# git line endings behavior does not match documentation

Tags: git, line-endings

I'm seeing git do things with line endings which seems to contradict everything I've seen on this site and the official docs and even its own warning messages.  (Or maybe I fail at reading comprehension.)  Here's a small reproduction.

```
# repro.sh
git --version # 2.27.0.windows.1
mkdir empty
cd empty
echo '* text=auto !eol' > .gitattributes
echo hi > t.txt
git init
git config core.autocrlf false # I guess git attributes overrides this anyway?
git add t.txt # wait what?  warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in t.txt???  I thought git likes LF?
git commit -m 'the plot thickens'
git cat-file -p `git rev-parse HEAD:t.txt` > temp.txt # get raw blob as its really stored, I hope
od -c t.txt # original file in working dir ends in LF
od -c temp.txt # file from git also ends in LF, despite git warning??
# end of script
```

Does this make any sense?  I thought that git sometimes likes to convert CRLF to plain LF on "git add" and does the reverse on checkout, but I've never heard of it turning plain LF into CRLF on git add, as the warning seems to threaten.  And then it doesn't do it.  The file that gets checked in is exactly what I have in my working directory, as verified by cat-file.  So why warn at all?  What's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The message itself has always seemed a bit ... wrong? weird? ill-phrased?—I'm not sure what to call it.  The *intent* of the message is to warn you that something seems inconsistent: that the way you see the file in the future may not be compatible with the way you see the file right now.

With that in mind, let's get to specifics:

> ```
> echo '* text=auto !eol' > .gitattributes
> ```

First, on `text=auto`: this sets the `text` attribute to a string value `auto`, which tells Git: *please guess whether each file is text or binary*.  I personally think this is a bad idea: you don't want Git to guess.  You should just tell it.  Git's guesses are usually pretty good, but I don't like my software to guess that much. :-)

In any case, let's move on to `!eol`: this means to set the `eol` attribute to the *unspecified* state.  This may not be what you want.  It *starts* unspecified, so if you don't want to specify it, you can just leave it unspecified.  The `!` prefix exists so that you can *correct* some previous setting: for instance, if the default should be `eol=lf`, you might have:

```
* eol=lf
```

but since JPG files should not be munged we can then override this just for `*.jpg`:

```
*.jpg !eol
```

(although `*.jpg binary` is probably better: it means `-diff -merge -text` and with `-text` the `eol` attribute becomes *irrelevant*).

So, what we have so far is: *a file is text if and only if Git guesses that it's text*, and *the eol attribute is unspecified*.

> ```
> git config core.autocrlf false # I guess git attributes overrides this anyway?
> ```

The `text` attribute specifically overrides this one.  [The gitattributes documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) says, in part:

> If the `text` attribute is unspecified, Git uses the
> `core.autocrlf` configuration variable to determine if the file
> should be converted.

This doesn't say what happens if the `text` attribute is *specified* (which it is, to `auto`), but going back just a bit, we find that with `text=auto`:

> If Git decides that the content is text, its line endings are converted to LF on checkin. When the file has been committed with CRLF, no conversion is done.

This talks only about *checkin*.  The documentation doesn't say this, but that's really during `git add`, which is when Git will, maybe, turn CRLF into LF-only.

> ```
> git add t.txt # wait what?  warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in t.txt???
> ```

Git emits these warnings during `git add` (unless they're suppressed through other configurations) when it notices anything suspicious.  The warnings are, or at least include, what you've seen, which I sometimes call ill-phrased (for lack of a better term).  I don't have a better way to phrase them that's not so verbose that it becomes problematic, though.

#### Warning: verbose = problematic description here

There are only two built-in LF/CRLF conversions:

- An "on the way in" conversion that turns CRLF into LF-only: this happens during only `git add`, and then only if it is, or seems to be, called-for.
- An "on the way out" conversion that turns LF-only into CRLF: this happens during `git checkout`, `git reset --hard`, `git restore` (if run with an explicit or implied `--worktree`), and other similar operations.  But, like the on-the-way-in CRLF-to-LF conversion, it only happens if it is or seems-to-be called-for.

What is happening here is that Git is *suspicious* that you'll have an LF-to-CRLF conversion occur on the way out, some time in the future.  I *think* your setup is not configured this way right now, because you have `!eol` and are on Linux (you are on Linux? maybe not: you said `windows` in a version string).  So maybe your setup *is* configured this way right now because you have `!eol` and are on Windows.  I don't use Windows, so I'm not sure what the defaults *are* on Windows.

Meanwhile, though, `t.txt`, as seen in both your index and your working tree, has pure LF-only line endings.  If Git were to perform an on-the-way-out LF-to-conversion (from index copy to working tree copy), your `t.txt` file in your *working tree* would suddenly have CRLF line endings.

That's what this warning message means.  If, in the future, Git does text conversion on the file, the result of extracting what's now in Git's index won't match the *actual* file in your *working tree* **right now**.  The one conversion that Git *can* do here is to turn LF-only into CRLF, and `t.txt` is currently LF-only.

#### On to the last few steps

> ```
> git commit -m 'the plot thickens'
> ```

The plot hasn't really thickened, here.  All conversions happened before this point.  The commit command merely takes the `t.txt` file stored in Git's index (that's the only file in Git's index at this point since the repository is all-new) and makes a commit out of that.

> ```
> git cat-file -p `git rev-parse HEAD:t.txt` > temp.txt
> # get raw blob as its really stored, I hope
> ```

This does, yes.  You could equally grab `:t.txt` from the index, or use `git ls-files --stage` to get the blob hash ID.

Note that the `git commit` step *has not modified the working tree copy*.  It's still untouched.  To force Git to extract the index copy back to the working tree, first remove the working tree copy, then use any Git command that will create it afresh.  This will run the extraction step, which will—or won't—turn LF-only to CRLF as requested by your various configurations:

```
rm t.txt
git checkout -- t.txt
```

You can now use `od` or similar to see what happened.  Did `\n` become `\r\n`, or not?  That tells you how Git interprets your current setup (`core.autocrlf`, `core.eol`, and the various attributes in `.git/info/attributes` and `.gitattributes`) for this file.

Note: `git ls-files --eol` has, since Git 2.8, been able to tell you more about what's going on here.  It will, separately:

- examine what's in the index;
- examine what's in the working tree; and
- see which attributes apply

to each file that is presently in the index.

Comment: First... wow, this is a thorough answer!  I learned something new in almost every paragraph.  Second, before I forget: yes, I meant "add t.txt".  Thank you for that bit of mind reading :)  I edited the question to require less mind reading.  Third: I am indeed on windows.  I just tried git checkout -- t.txt and indeed I ended up with crlf line endings.  I feel that I have finally been enlightened.

Comment: Fourth: I think I have a way to make the message clearer without making it too much longer: "LF will be replaced by CRLF on next checkout of this file".  In other words, emphasize the conversion will happen later, instead of implying it's happening now.  If aiming for terseness, this is just two extra words: "on checkout".

Comment: Now that life makes sense again, I wonder if there's a way to re-title this question for improved searchability.   I feel like this answer should be the first result for any search involving this warning.  Seriously, this is an amazingly thorough answer.

Comment: @MarkVY: I like that message suggestion. You might consider offering it to the Git mailing list as a patch to Git. (Sending fixes for Git is ... a big time investment / time-sink, but helps many people.)

Comment: Perhaps I could simply suggest the improved wording without making an actual patch in the hopes that an official maintainer will like it and create the patch themselves?

Comment: Mentioned on mailing list but discussion kind of trailed off... https://www.spinics.net/lists/git/msg406680.html

Comment: I saw that. A bunch of people think the existing documentation text and/or messages from the convert code is/are sufficient, and I'm pretty certain it is/they are not. So there are multiple barriers to climb here, which is why I suggested that you send it in as an actual patch. :-)

Comment: Ah.  You saw this coming :)  Do you really think that would help much though?  For a git maintainer, this is trivial patch, at least once the wording is agreed on.  For an outsider like me, preparing a proper patch is a large undertaking.  I'd have to clone git, figure out how to build it, find the relevant place in the code, etc.  If they don't like the my wording, then I don't see that saving them a few minutes of work will change their mind much.

Comment: I don't really know. There's a marketing / financial term, "friction", for the problem (see https://www.investopedia.com/terms/f/frictioncost.asp) but for something like this it's not obvious how to compute the frictional cost here, and whether a patch vs just wording-suggestion makes much difference. (Note that even once it's in, there's still more work, e.g., for language translators coming up with the `.po` files.)

Comment: I guess I could ask on the mailing list if a patch is likely to help?

Comment: by the way, thank you again for this answer, I've had to refer to it once more